# Selenium Test Case/Suite

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

My Selenium Test Case and Test Suite is not working properly, for some reason when I play each test case separately, it works, however, when I play the whole thing together, it says: *'Element ... not found'* and also, if I add both test cases to a new test case and play this new test case, it doesn't work. I am assuming my first test case is fine as that always works, but it gets the element not found error at this point, and I have tried other ways as well:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains(., 'Volume Entry')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I also tried replacing the '//div' with:

```
css=.btn_sel_text:contains('Volume Entry')
```

however that didn't work either. Can anyone please explain why it doesn't work when I run the whole thing together, however, if I simply run the `//div` or the 'css' on it's own it does work.

Comment: This sounds like a race condition. Add `waitForElementPresent` before. Also don't use that CSS selector, there is no `contains` CSS selector and therefore it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @Arran
I tried that, but it said Timed out after 30000ms and then when it moved on to the click I get the same error 'Element... not found' as before. I had placed the same Target in the `waitForElementPresent` as I had for the click which is `//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains(., 'Volume Entry')]`

Comment: Can you show us a copy of the page, or a public facing site where we can reproduce this?

Comment: @Arran
Not sure if it will help much but here ![IMAGE](http://s24.postimage.org/9cq41phdv/Screen1.png) you go. I am trying to click on Volume Entry which is accessed from the arrow besides 'Volume'.

Comment: Surely you'd need to click the arrow first then to make it visible?

Comment: @Arran I thought I would do that, but all the other items, that have arrows have the exact same code, so how would I get it to pick the one for Volume and not any of the other ones:
`<div class="dhx_toolbar_arw def" title="">`
`<div class="arwimg"> </div>`
`</div>`

Comment: I would need to see the HTML around the 'Volume' menu to give you a direct answer.

Comment: @Arran
This is the code for the Volume and Arrow:
`<div class="dhx_toolbar_btn def" title="">
<div>Volume</div>
</div>
<div class="dhx_toolbar_arw def" title="">
<div class="arwimg"> </div>
</div>`

Comment: @Arran
And this is the code for the Volume Drop-Down list:
`<div class="dhx_toolbar_poly_dhx_skyblue" dir="ltr" style="display: none; z-index: 101;">
<table class="buttons_cont" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="tr_btn">
</tr>
<tr class="tr_btn">
<td class="td_btn_img"></td>
<td class="td_btn_txt">
<div class="btn_sel_text">Volume Entry</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_btn">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>`
I removed the 2 other items from the drop-down list to save space.

Answer (score 0):

put a pause before click.

command:pause

Target:3000

Try it,Thank you.

Comment: I tried that, again when I run before click and click as two separate cases it works, however when I run them as 1 case or 1 suit it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.
Think I might just leave the whole thing as multiple cases and write a script to run each case in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Find Xpath of that element using firepath. with Xpath of element you can click on it. do this & let me know your problem is solved or not

```
<tr>
<td>pause</td>
<td></td>
<td>1500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>Xpath of the element </td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It didn't but thanks anyway. I decided to simply make a test case for each new thing I'm testing, and then I'll write a script to run all the cases in a specific order. **+** It'll allow me to test specific things on their own rather than running the test again for the whole site every time a small item doesn't work.
But thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: use always Xpath for button and textbox and try, I think you do not get minor error in the script. if this answer work you then accept my answer

Comment: I have used XPath I believe:
    `<tr>
 <td>pause</td>
 <td>1500</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains(., 'Volume Entry')]</td>
 <td></td>
    </tr>`

Comment: It only works when I run it separately, not when I run it together.

Comment: Can you paste sample script here ? so I can check it, because I run 15 test case together but I am not getting such type of error

Comment: <tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=img[alt=&quot;Login&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>windowFocus</td>
    <td>title=Example</td>
    <td></td>
    <tr/>
is a part of the first test case
    <tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1500</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains(., 'Volume Entry')]</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>

Comment: use this code and let me know it work or not

<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=img[alt=&quot;Login&quot;]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>windowFocus</td>
 <td>title=Example</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>pause</td>
 <td>1500</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains('Volume Entry')]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: So, is the only difference `contains(., 'Volume Entry)]` which becomes `contains('Volume Entry')]`?
****EDIT****  
I tried that, but I still get the same error, and now also can't run the second case on it's own.

Comment: you get error due to `contains(., 'Volume Entry)]`, try to cross check you xpath(//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains(., 'Volume Entry')]) of button, if you find your Xpath accurately then your problem is solved, try to record second test case again with selenium ide

Comment: I did try to record the second test against with Selenium IDE, and I got this: `css=tr.tr_btn.tr_btn_selected > td.td_btn_txt > div.btn_sel_text` which didn't work when I run both tests as a suit, and the alternative to that that it gave is: `//div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div` which also didn't work when I ran both tests as a suit, however they do work when I run them on their own cases, just like my code has been doing.

Comment: Unistall selenium ide from fire fox and again reinstall selenium ide then try

Comment: I did remove Selenium IDE from Firefox and then tried it again, but I still get the same error.

Comment: if you give me your full code then I will run it in on my system and let you know what is the issue ?

Comment: The 1st case: `<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=img[alt=&quot;Login&quot;]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>windowFocus</td>
 <td>title=Example</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>`
_The 2nd case:_
`<tr>
 <td>pause</td>
 <td>1500</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@class='btn_sel_text' and contains(., 'Volume Entry')]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>`
_or even:_ `<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>` _instead of the last click._

Comment: Dear Friend if you give me url of site, so that I can record a fresh test case and send back to you or please give whole code to me this 4 line is not help me I needed whole test suit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't as it is a service site, and requires a log in.  
  Thank you for all your help though.

Comment: give me url I will create My own login and send script to you.

Comment: Only an Admin can create a login, and I am not an Admin for the site.

Comment: Ok thanks, no problem. Please check ID of button is dynamic or static

Comment: There is no ID, only class, but other buttons use the same class, which is why I had to use the and contains(., 'Volume Entry'). But yes, the class is static

Comment: can you send me snapshot of button with inspect element(firebug) ?

Comment: `<div class="btn_sel_text">Volume Entry</div>`

Comment: what is ID of this class ?

Comment: There is no ID being used. Just class.

Comment: User fire path addon on FF browser to find correct Xpath ofbutton, your Xpath is wrong.

Comment: Send me snapshot of your CSS of this button, so I will give you correct path of button

Comment: This is the XPath I get when using XPath Checker:
`/x:html/x:body/x:div[13]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td[2]/x:div` and I am looking through the FirePath code right now.

Comment: Use Firepath addons to find Xpath, once you find correct Xpath of button then your problem is definitely solved.

Comment: How exactly would I get the XPath using FirePath. Whenever I right-click on the item and click on _Inspect Element with FireBug_ it takes me to the html. From there, when I click on FirePath I have to search through the whole code it displays, and there is no Search Function available in FirePath.

Comment: See video and learn how to use Fire path addons in FF - http://screencast.com/t/E5pnGYMxE

Comment: Thank You. This is the XPath I got from FirePath:
`html/body/div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div`

Comment: Do I use it exactly like that or do I change it to `//div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div`?

Comment: use exactly like this do not do any change - html/body/div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div

Comment: When I use it exactly like that, I get _Element ... not found_ but when I use `//div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div` it works on it's own and in the test case, but not when I run the test suit.

Comment: Also, `html/body/div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div` doesn't work on it's own either

Comment: div[13]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div - try this, it is working fine.

Comment: Same thing again. It works on it's own and when run as a test case, however it doesn't work when run in the test suit.

Comment: Exactly I dont know why this happen.

Comment: Well, Thank You for your help. I think I will just write a script once I'm done with each case to run the cases in a specific order. That way each case is run separately, and not as a suit, which should work then.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to debug this problem for myself, I found that if I had two test cases that worked individually and then when I ran them together in a test suite a link/button could not be found in the second test case, the solution was actually to modify the FIRST test case.

If you have more than two test cases, try changing the order around so that there is some other test case immediately following the original first test case. When I tried that, my error moved from the original second test case to the new second test case.

I don't know exactly why, but it is like Selenium is unable to catch up with the effects of the first test on the browser or something. If add, however, a 'pause 5000' followed by a ClickAndWait (to an inocuous link that keeps me on the same page, perhaps) to the end of the
first test case, then when the first and second test case are run together in the test suite, the second test case now works.